# Postgres SQL - copy data from one column to another and if null from another one

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need a help with some challenge

How can I (using sql script for PostgreSQL)  copy data from column A to B if A is NULL and if B is null as well copy data from column C?

So if A is null copy data from B but if B is also Null copy from column C.
All data are in same table.

Is it possible?

Comment: Show us some sample table data, both before and after versions. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: I don't have them yet. In general column A is new and pretty much empty, script should copy string value from column B to A, but if B is NULL  then should copy data from column C but only if A is NULL. This is just a future case so column A doesn't exist yet

Comment: Just make something up, a few rows having different null /not null combinations.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps `COALESCE` is what you want here with an update:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET A = COALESCE(B, C)
WHERE A IS NULL;
```

This logic would update records with a `NULL` value for `A` with values from `B`, or if the `B` values also be `NULL`, from `C`.